# How to do sorting of server data displaying on the screen

Tags: java, java-me

I am making an application in which I am getting the data from the server. That data is not in the sorted format I need to do sorting of the data and then display.

Server is sending the data in the sorting order but when I am displaying that data is not coming in sorted manner.

```
Vendor5:   "13210129.00"
Vendor1:  "6439080.00",
Vendor4:  "3635507.00",
NV12 :    "724167.00",
New Inf:"445143.00",
OV15":  "98634.00",
FV6":   "94654.00",
KV10":  "84893.00",
PV16"  :"76832.00","
Tv23":   "65443.00",
PV4":"  34509.00",
MV14":  "9743.00"
JV9":"  7539.00",
LV11":  "6439.00",
YV3":"   5900.00"
```

Now after doing the parsing of that data I am displaying them bui it is not coming in sorted form on the screen so please help me out. Parsing code is:

```
CrDrList.VendorNameArr[i] = CrDrList.myvendor;

                    i++;
                }

                for (int j = 0; j < property.CrDrlength; j++) {
                    if (jonew.has(CrDrList.VendorNameArr[j])) {
                        CrDrList.VendorValArr[j] = jonew
                                .getString(CrDrList.VendorNameArr[j]);

                    }
                }
```

And displaying code is:

```
        LabelField Value = new LabelField(CrDrList.VendorValArr[i]);

        hfm.add(CrDrLabels[i]);
        hfm.add(Value);
```